# Any general (xml?) format for defining (input params of) command line tools?

Tags: xml, command-line, wrapper, command-line-arguments, file-format

Is there anything such as a general (xml or similar) format for defining command line tools, such as input params and outputs?

The format must be detailed enough to serve as the basis for automatically generating wizards for filling in the inputs required by a tool.

I already found the [xml-based format](https://bitbucket.org/galaxy/galaxy-central/wiki/ToolConfigSyntax) created by Bioinformatics integration workbench Galaxy. Problem is that the xml files in Galaxy toolconfig format are not independent, but need an accompanying python (.py) file that does some logic, and which does not follow any defined format, making it hard to port to other languages.

So, looking for other suggestions!

Comment: I think the docbooks collection includes definitions for command-line tools, but I am in no way expert in xml or docbooks, but it might be worth a quick look. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds itneresting. Do you happen to have any link for where to look for it?

Comment: http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/cmdsynopsis.html

Comment: Thanks! Looks to be pretty much what I looked for ... feel free to add as a proper answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docbooks collection includes XML definitions for [command-line tools](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/cmdsynopsis.html).

I'm glad that helped. It was a interesting question.

P.S.

Did you consider using a java like config file? i.e.

```
$ cat any.properties
javadoc.additionalparam=
javadoc.author=false
javadoc.encoding=
javadoc.noindex=false
javadoc.nonavbar=false
javadoc.notree=false
```

While I am learning about XML, I still don't preceive much advantage at the scale that I work at, do you? ;-)

Comment: Well, the main reasons why I like XML, is first that often there is a "standard XML format" for many things, which increases the chance to find already existing content (like command line tool defs). Otherwise, I guess it has the advantage of not being (programming) language specific, the ubiquity of XML tools in dofferent languages, plus at last, I think nested data is very robustly handled in XML. (Guess thats my 5c :) ).

Comment: great, thanks for sharing those insights. For me, I think it is a matter of scale and experience. There are definitely some things that can only be done with XML, so I'm going to keep at it. Thanks